# I want to locate a link which is in a div tag under a section tag in Selenium Java with IE

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

Actually I have same `href` links in different sections. I want to access a particular `href` in a particular section. But in in each sections there are many `div` tags and under one of the `div` tag this particular `href` is located. Please help me to find the locator in IE. I am sharing code snippet and I have highlighted the href tag whose locator I am seeking:

```
   <html>
    <head></head>
    <section id="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="top-nav">
                <a href="#" class="quick-nav" data-toggle="popover" id="languageChooser" data-original-title title>..</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="main-menu">
        <nav id="nav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-main" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse in" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="true">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li menuitemname="Account" class="dropdown" id="Secondary_Navbar-Account">
                            **<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">..</a>**
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">..</ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </section>
    .
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: you have differetn options.. 1. use Selenium(browser needed) 2.use JSoup(no need of a browser)

Comment: can you share a part of relevant `HTML` snippet.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Use : //li[@id='Secondary_Navbar-Account]/a to find that element then you can get any attribute value from that element.

Answer (score 0):

Following `xpath` will help you to get the element :

```
//li[@id='Secondary_Navbar-Account]/a
```

Following can be used to get `href` value from the element :

```
element.getAttribute("href")
```

Do let me know if this is as required

Answer (score 0):

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".dropdown-toggle")).click();

This worked out for me. As its IE I was not able to use Xpath .

Answer (score 0):

Following xpath can be used to locate the required WebElement:

```
//div[@id='bs-example-navbar-collapse-1']/following::li[@menuitemname='Account']/a
```

Please let me know, whether it works for you.